# Is it possible to typecast void* to float* otherthan using reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++11, reinterpret-cast, typecasting-operator

```
float* val= reinterpret_cast<float*>(memcpy());
```

As we know, memcpy() method returns void pointer(void*).

Is it possible to typecast void* to float* other than reinterpret_cast? Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to typecast `void*` to `float*` other than reinterpret_cast? Somebody please help.

You can use C-style cast: `(float*)memcpy(...)`.

However, both could be wrong depending on what the arguments to `memcpy` are.

If you use:

```
 float src[10] = { ... }; // Initialize to some values
 float dest[10];

 float* p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(src));
```

It's perfectly fine since `memcpy` returns `dest`, which is valid as a `float*`.

However, if you use:

```
 int src[10] = { ... }; // Initialize to some values
 int dest[10];

 float* p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(src));
```

Your program will have undefined behavior.

Using C-style cast is OK though not preferable for the first case. It will lead to undefined behavior in the second case.

You may also use `static_cast`.

```
float* p = static_cast<float*>(memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(src));
```

Comment: Yeah it is fine that can use c-style cast or reinterpret_cast. These cast types are known. Is there any other way to cast other than these methods- Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Prakash, You may also use `static_cast`.

Comment: @Sahu, Static_cast doesn't useful in all these cases.

Comment: @Prakash, I am not sure what answer you are looking for. Is it related to only the call to `memcpy`? Is there a wider problem that you are trying to get an answer to? If your problem concerns only `memcpy`, why do you need any other methods of casting the return value than `reinterpret_cast`? Even there, you obviously have `dest` as a variable, Can you simply not use it? What's the need for casting at all? Just curious.

Comment: @Sahu I have just given example memcpy() which returns void*. My major concern is to convert void* to float*. I would like to know is it possible to write our own method to convert the same. If yes, I just need some inputs.

Comment: @Prakash, you can cast a `void*` to a `float*` using any of the methods as long as the underlying objects are `float`s. It does not matter whether the function being called is `memcpy` or something else.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Sahu.